# Retrieve values in PHP,MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM course_completion_criteria GROUP BY module');

foreach($check as $c)
{
   $module = $c->module; //echo $module;
   if($module == 'quiz')
   {
      $query1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table1');     
      echo '<table>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time</th>
      foreach($query1 as $q)
      {
         $name = $q->name;
         $time = $q->time;
         echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td>
                   <td>'.$time.'</td>
               </tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
   } 

   if($module == 'scorm')
   {
      $query2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table2');
      echo '<table>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Time</th>
      foreach($query1 as $q)
      {
         $name = $q->name;
         $time = $q->time;
         echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td>
                   <td>'.$time.'</td>
               </tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
   } 
}
```

The above code should work
case 1 : If $module is test1
case 2 : If $module is test2
case 3 : If $module is both test1 and test2

My code isn't working in CASE 3 and it displays two tables, but i want 2rows in the same table
Could anyone help me?

Comment: How can `$module` be both "test1" and "test2" at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one error

```
if($module = 'test1')
```

should be

```
if($module == 'test1')
```

Also read about switch/case statement in PHP

UPD: Case 3 code

```
$module = []
foreach($check as $c)
{
   $module[] = $c->module; //echo $module;
}
if (count($module) == 1) {
  if($module == 'quiz')
  {
     //CASE_1
  } 

   if($module == 'scorm')
   {
     //CASE_2
   } 
}else{
   //CASE_3
}
```

Comment: But this isn't the error, may be posted here was the mistake, I will correct now

Comment: hm Then I don't really understand what means CASE 3? $module is a string. How does string can be BOTH test1 and test2?

Comment: This is in MOODLE. Admin will set quiz and scorm in frontend to complete a course and student completes both to complete a course. Now Iam getting the activity either quiz or scorm from criteria table and checking them                                                            Here Admin can set either only quiz/ only scorm / one quiz and one scorm. I was able to get output for first two, but in third case Iam getting two tables but need one table with 2 different rows(quiz,scorm)

Comment: Lol I'm still not sure that understand your idea, but look at code in UPD.

Comment: Ya the code was ok, but I don't have a separate query for CASE 3. Like If $module is quiz, then first query should execute and If $module is scorm, then second query should execute in different rows but not in two tables

Answer (score 0):

You dont have condition for case3:

```
else {  //for CASE3
$query3 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_you_want_data_from');
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudhir, Can we do any modifications in the above code to get CASE 3 here